# Fake Shortcuts in Windows - Is there an API? One for C#?

Tags: .net, winapi, shortcut

I'm not sure what they call the fake shortcuts you often see in Windows now. A good example would be the link to any of the Office 2007 programs. You can tell one of these from a regular shortcut because the Target is grayed out and is not a real path. Can you access these through a .NET API? Like ask for the target? or get any of the information stored within it.

I think these are somehow related to Windows Installer and Advertised programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a advertised shortcut.

you have to call the windows installer to get the target.

currently i have only a delphi source for you, but perhaps you can pick some informations out.

[delphi-library](http://www.delphi-library.de/topic_Die+ausfuehrbare+Datei+eines+quotadvertised+shortcutquot+ermitteln_51393.html)

in short - it uses the **MsiGetShortcutTarget** function to get the target.